# Mapping one object to another with aggregation and grouping

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

Mapping one object to another with aggregation and grouping

I have a class

```
class Q {
    String username;
    int taskId;
    double timediff;

   // constructor
}
```

and I need to convert it to

```
 class ToQ {
        String username;
        int noOfTasks;
        double sum;

       // constructor
    }
```

So the intension is group by username, count no of taskIds, sum of timediff.

List of this

```
List<Q> qs = new ArrayList<>();
    qs.add(new Q("tom", 2, 2.0));
    qs.add(new Q("tom", 6, 1.0));
    qs.add(new Q("harry", 8, 0.03));
```

Should have output of ToQ as

```
new ToQ("tom",2,3);
new ToQ("harry",1,0.03);
```

I tried with grouping function but it generates HashMap but not sure how to convert into object.

```
Map<String, Double> collect = qs
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Q::getUsername, summingDouble(Q::getLocalDateTime)));
```

Comment: whats the relation between 'stark' and 'tom', I wonder?

Comment: they are same :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

#### Group by Name for TimeDiff

```
Map<String, Double> nameToTimeDiffSumMap = qs.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Q::getUsername, 
                Collectors.summingDouble(Q::getTimediff)));
```

#### Group by Name for Count

```
Map<String, Long> nameToCountMap = qs.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Q::getUsername, 
                Collectors.counting()));
```

#### Form a `List<ToQ>`

```
List<ToQ> toQS = qs.stream().map(a -> 
        new ToQ(a.getUsername(), nameToCountMap.get(a.getUsername()), nameToTimeDiffSumMap.get(a.getUsername())))
        .collect(toList());
```

which assumes the classes to have *getters* and *setters* and appropriate *constructor* as well

```
class ToQ {
    String username;
    long noOfTasks;
    double sum;
}

class Q {
    String username;
    int taskId;
    double timediff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This *might* better done via the `toMap` collector:

```
Collection<ToQ> values = qs.stream().collect(toMap(Q::getUsername,
            v -> new ToQ(v.getUsername(), 1, v.getTimediff()),
            (l, r) -> {
                l.setNoOfTasks(l.getNoOfTasks() + r.getNoOfTasks());
                l.setSum(l.getSum() + r.getSum());
                return l;
            })).values();
```

This assumes you have a `Q` constructor as follows:

```
public ToQ(String username, int noOfTasks, double sum) {...}
```

if you wish to persist with the `groupingBy`, then you can do it as follows:

```
List<ToQ> result = qs.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Q::getUsername))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .map(l -> new ToQ(l.get(0).getUsername(), l.size(), l.stream().mapToDouble(Q::getTimediff).sum()))
                .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I actually want the final output as Collection<ToQ>. I will go through your answer.

Answer (score 1):

the simple way would be like this: use `toMap()` with merge function.

```
 Map<String, ToQ> map = qs.stream()
      .collect(toMap(Q::getUsername, q -> new ToQ(q.username, q.taskId, q.timediff), ToQ::merge));
 List<ToQ> toQList =  new ArrayList<>( map.values());
```

and define a method in ToQ:

```
public ToQ merge(ToQ q){
     this.noOfTasks+=q.noOfTasks;
     this.sum+=q.sum;
     return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a *one liner* too :

```
List<ToQ> toQS = qs.stream()
    .map(Q::getUserName)
    .distinct()
    .map(userName -> new ToQ(
        userName,
        qs.stream()
            .map(Q::getUserName)
            .filter(userName::equals)
            .count(),
        qs.stream()
            .map(Q::getUserName)
            .filter(q -> Objects.equals(userName, q.getUserName()))
            .mapToDouble(Q::getTimeDiff)
            .sum()
    ))
    .collect(toList())
```